# Python: ImportError: cannot import name 'bincount'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When i import an algorithm from sklearn library, i am getting an error message as - ImportError: Cannot import name 'bincount'. I never faced this error and could not find an equivalent answer here. Please help

```
import sklearn
sklearn.__version__

Out[1]:

'0.19.1'


from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
```

**Output of Error**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-4a3086242da3> in <module>()
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      4 get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')
----> 5 from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

C:\Users\30295\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\__init__.py in <module>()
      5 
      6 from .base import BaseEnsemble
----> 7 from .forest import RandomForestClassifier
      8 from .forest import RandomForestRegressor
      9 from .forest import RandomTreesEmbedding

C:\Users\30295\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py in <module>()
     55 from ..externals.joblib import Parallel, delayed
     56 from ..externals import six
---> 57 from ..metrics import r2_score
     58 from ..preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
     59 from ..tree import (DecisionTreeClassifier, DecisionTreeRegressor,

C:\Users\30295\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\__init__.py in <module>()
      5 
      6 
----> 7 from .ranking import auc
      8 from .ranking import average_precision_score
      9 from .ranking import coverage_error
C:\Users\30295\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\ranking.py in <module>()
     30 from ..utils.multiclass import type_of_target
     31 from ..utils.extmath import stable_cumsum
---> 32 from ..utils.sparsefuncs import count_nonzero
     33 from ..exceptions import UndefinedMetricWarning
     34 from ..preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

C:\Users\30295\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\sparsefuncs.py in <module>()
      7 import numpy as np
      8 
----> 9 from .fixes import sparse_min_max, bincount
     10 from .sparsefuncs_fast import (
     11     csr_mean_variance_axis0 as _csr_mean_var_axis0,

ImportError: cannot import name 'bincount'
```

Comment: That code doesn't appear in version 0.19.1. You may have a corrupt install; try uninstalling and reinstalling scikit-learn.

Comment: [Here's what `sparsefuncs.py` is supposed to look like in scikit-learn 0.19.1.](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.19.1/sklearn/utils/sparsefuncs.py)

Comment: @user2357112 - you are right. Seems something has corrupted. as you suggested, I have reinstalled scikit-learn. Now it is working fine. Thanks for the help.